# Base64 decode image PHP

Tags: php, encoding, base64, decode, encode

I am trying to decode an image blob from SQL database ( where it is stored after base64_encode) in PHP.

I am using

```
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-control: max-age=0');
header('Content-Type: image');
header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
header("Vary: Accept-Encoding");
echo gzencode( base64_decode ($result[0]['Icon']) ); // result is the result of query from DB
```

While it works some time when my browser language is English but it does not decode properly if my browser language is other than English.

I am debugging with charles proxy to look at the response. I am not able to post the response here. The size of the response for English is 3 bytes less than other responses.

But for other languages it comes as something like this with extra 3 bytes.

```
T�e�s�t�i�n�g� �
```

I checked the DB for the encoded string for the image. It is the same in DB but different when the response is sent. Hence the image is displayed correctly if the language is English but broken if the language is not English. Please help me.

Comment: Why are you using gzencode()? What happens if you drop that extra step and simply echo base64_decode(...)?

Comment: Remove the gzencode, though its going to output the raw image data, not most likely what you expect; an image, you need to set the content type correct headers

Comment: @Peter Even if I remove the gzencode the response is similar except for much larger sized response.

Comment: @LozCherone I have set all the headers correctly. I have included the headers that I had set.

Comment: Well `Content-Type: image` is wrong for a start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this fixed myself.The reason is because PHP is adding a UTF-8 byte order mark (BOM) at the beginning. So this problem gets fixed when the output buffer is cleaned using ob_clean();
The following worked perfectly.

```
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-control: max-age=0');
header('Content-Type: image');
header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
header("Vary: Accept-Encoding");
ob_clean();
echo gzencode( base64_decode ($result[0]['Icon']) ); // result is the result of query from DB
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know name of the image or at least extension? You have to use it in your header Content-Type. For example header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

Comment: The name of the image varies according to the request. But the content type is png.

Comment: So use this: header('Content-Type: image/png'); echo base64_decode ($result[0]['Icon']);